# laravel default localizations for other languages?

Tags: locale, default, laravel-5

A new Laravel project already comes with some localizations, in english.

```
.
└── en
    ├── auth
    │   ├── form.php
    │   └── message.php
    ├── button.php
    ├── general.php
    ├── groups
    │   ├── form.php
    │   ├── message.php
    │   ├── modal.php
    │   ├── table.php
    │   └── title.php
    ├── pagination.php
    ├── passwords.php
    ├── reminders.php
    ├── users
    │   ├── message.php
    │   ├── modal.php
    │   └── title.php
    └── validation.php
```

Are those files available for other languages, too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people have published a few. See for example https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang